# How to print fixed fraction part in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

my query -

```
select type, round(cast(sum(cost) as numeric),4) as amount
from table
group by 1
order by amount desc
limit 3
```

I have tried multiple ways in place of - **round(cast(sum(cost) as numeric),4)** but I can't see four zero's after the decimal point. In case the amount is fractional in nature it works, but in the case where the amount is an integer, I am not able to get four zeros after the point.

my output -

+------+------------+
type    amount
+------+------------+
A         6000.0
C         5000.0
B         3000.0
+------+------------+

expected output -

+------+------------+
type    amount
+------+------------+
A         6000.0000
C         5000.0000
B         3000.0000
+------+------------+

Comment: [Runs as you want for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9c527c20beb543cbcc9efe183e48b851)

Comment: Hey Sorry! it's not PostgreSQL but MySQL. Does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
select type, round(sum(cost)::numeric,4)::TEXT as amount
from table
group by 1
order by amount desc
limit 3
```

Comment: it is throwing an error at : , says it's unidentified.

Comment: Here an [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/34d61/13/0). I try it online and it's working

Comment: Hey Sorry, the underlying DB is MySQL, the error says : token no recognized.